multi device/session login support in ory kratos
I'd like to implement that login scenario in my service:
I have mobile app and web app. User already logged in on mobile, and want to login to the web app.
So, on the web page user clicks "Login on mobile" and somehow (not a subject of the question) allows login attempt on the mobile.
Question is, does Ory Kratos/Hydra supports such scenario?
I've read MFA section in the docs, but it's very brief.
Maybe there is a some plugins machinery, hooks or something else?
Almost forgot, I'm talking about self-hosted Ory.

After further doc's reading, I figured out, that I can place my own auth service in front of Kratos. Intercept login attempt, exchange codes with mobile and then finish login flow. So, question is, could it be simpler?
